# Passing variable value to another tab (JPanel)

Tags: java, swing

I was looking for the solution, but the problem still remains. I'm designing a GUI and trying to change the variable by clicking a button:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    var=(String)jComboBox2.getSelectedItem();
}
```

Then i want to use it to change label in another tab, which already exist, but it always says null (value of the variable is not updated even though it is defined in the most-upper class.
I was trying with:

```
jLabel4.revalidate();
jLabel4.repaint();
```

but it also fails.

---

Ok, I will explain it better :D I have a button defined as follows:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                         
var=(String)jComboBox2.getSelectedItem();
jLabel4.revalidate(); //actually makes no difference if i delete this 2 lines...
jLabel4.repaint();    }
```

And I want to use this variable in another tab (JPanel):

```
jLabel4.setText("Studenci z przedmiotu " + var);
```

but the variable var always remains null as defined in the mother class (this is quite logical, because all components are initiated at the start-up, before pressing the button...). But do you know why functions repaint and revalidate do not work? How can I substitute them? sry for not posting the whole code, but i think it will be too much spam ;d

Comment: Can you explain your problem better? You want, when I click on jButton2, that var become your selected item. Are you sure that your jComboBox contains String Objects?

Answer (score 0):

if you want change a Text variable use setText() Method in gui
For Example:

```
 jlable4.setText("new text");
```

and put it in your action like this:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        jlable4.setText("new text");
   }
```

if that was your question,Enjoy!if not give me a peace of code and tell me what is error message and i'be help you.